# iSCSI connection always alive, without the need of login

Tags: connection, storage, scsi, iscsi

Is there a way to keep the iSCSI connection alive for always.

For example in case of a connection error which results in a logout of the session, when the connectivity is restored, it does not have to go through all the steps of the iSCSI login like Command Write, Ready to transmit, and all.

Like how website login works. I know this is not a very good comparison, but may be someone can point out as to why the same thing cannot be implemented in iSCSI

*Note : I am looking for a way of doing this through any available initiator (in Linux or Windows), or even if there is a way of doing it in the iSCSI RFC.*

Answer (score 1):

You can try configuring your iSCSI kernel driver to ignore checking with NOP-Out/In PDUs, in other words ignore timeouts. For example, FreeBSD man [cfiscsi(4)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=cfiscsi&apropos=0&sektion=4&manpath=FreeBSD%2012.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) says:

```
kern.cam.ctl.iscsi.ping_timeout
         The number of seconds to wait for the iSCSI initiator to respond
         to a NOP-In PDU.  In the event that there is no response within
         that time the session gets forcibly terminated.  Set to 0 to dis-
         able sending NOP-In PDUs.  Defaults to 5.
```

But I believe it's not the right way to make your system resilient and reliable and etc.

Comment: Hmm.. interesting.. We can probably do this on the initiator side (Host). But that wont stop the target from destroying the session.. correct?

Comment: @Haris, from the same man: "The cfiscsi subsystem provides the kernel component of an iSCSI target". So this is about configuring target. On the client-side there is another kernel-variable for timeout: kern.iscsi.fail_on_disconnection - see iscsi(4)

Comment: A small addendum. On the client-side you can look at: kern.iscsi.ping_timeout and kern.iscsi.fail_on_disconnection variables. Hope, this helps.

Comment: ook.. So, the above mentioned configuration to disable sending NOP-In is for a SAN environment when a linux-like system is being used as a target (like FreeBSD). I wonder how many enterprise grade SAN arrays implement this and give an option to the user to configure.
Anyway, thanks for the info.. I will search through the RFC to see if there is any specification tied to this (or something similar).